# Azure DevOps Server start a scheduled build manually

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server

I'm trying to create a scheduled build. To check my syntax i tried to start the build **manually**, but got the following message:

[image: Printscreen Error Message]

My yaml file looks as follows:

```
name: $(Build.DefinitionName)_$(build.buildId)
trigger: none

schedules:
- cron: "0 2 * * Mon-Fri"
  displayName: M-F 3:00 AM
  branches:
    include:
    - master
```

Anybody a suggestion? Or is it simply impossible to start a scheduled build manually?

Comment: Even if you have a "schedule" trigger, you can still queue the build whenever you want... I think the error is in the YAML - you can set trigger to schedule and then queue the build, it should start immediately

Comment: @AmittaiShapira: What du so mean with "set the trigger to schedule"?

Comment: my bad, it looks like your syntax is fine, there's some discussion on scheduled triggers on the Microsoft developer community, you may want to start there (they're usually very helpful): https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/613157/new-cron-schedule-not-working.html

Comment: After `trigger: none` try adding the setting `pr: none` on a new line as I think this may also be required

Comment: @AmittaiShapira I've looked across that issue, but these it looks not equally to my mistake..

Comment: @MikeS Sounds good, nice idea. But: Not working... Still the same error (except the line number is +1)

Comment: May it's not supported by Azure DevOps Server 2019 OnPrem (17.143.28912.1 (AzureDevOps2019.0.1))?

Comment: Makes sense - Cron syntax was introduced in Azure DevOps Service Sprint 153, in June (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/pipelines/sprint-153-update) and Azure DevOps Server latest update was  2019.0.1 in May (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2019?view=azure-devops)

Comment: When Asking question regarding Azure DevOps on prem you may want to use the "azure-devops-server" tag, to avoid confusion with the cloud Azure DevOps Service

Comment: I‘m currently not at the office, gonna check it on monday. But I belive unfortunatelly yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that YAML Scheduled Triggers are not supported in Azure DevOps Server 2019, only in Azure DevOps Service, see the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops-2019#supported-cron-syntax):

> Scheduled builds are not yet supported in YAML syntax. After you
>   create your YAML build pipeline, you can use pipeline settings to
>   specify a scheduled trigger.